# Android Opencv: What feature extraction and matching method use to leaf recognition?

Tags: android, opencv, matching, feature-extraction

i have an android project to recognize leaf image. I have been using invariant moments to extract the shape feature of leaf, and using City Block Distance for matching. I want to use another feature extraction and matching method in opencv to recognize the leaf. So, what feature extraction and matching method should i use?

Comment: Do you mean local image features? Empirically I think they will not work very well to recognize leafs but you can always try it yourself and measure the accuracy for your data. You can start by ORB.

Comment: @RuiMarques thanks for the response, now i'm in project of using ORB, but i confused about to store the feature data. Anytime i input the image, the keypoint of the image always different. Can i store the feature to database? or must i store the image (as data to store the feature)?

Comment: You can store the features but maybe you should create a new question with that topic.

Comment: @RuiMarques this is the question i made for this topic, i hope u can help me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21849938/how-to-save-orb-feature-to-database

Comment: Hi. Fortunately I'm doing a project related to image processing and I'm in the feature extraction phase, please can you let me know the resources you've used and what featured you've extracted to detect the leaf?