# Android Opencv: Save ORB features using Json

Tags: android, json, opencv, feature-extraction, orb

i want to save orb features to database that i get from this code:

```
bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.t1);
Utils.bitmapToMat(bmp, mat);
FeatureDetector detector = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.ORB);
detector.detect(mat, keypoints);
DescriptorExtractor extractor = DescriptorExtractor.create(DescriptorExtractor.ORB);
extractor.compute(mat, keypoints, features);
```

i using json code to save the data from Mat of feature with the code i get from here:
http://answers.opencv.org/question/8873/best-way-to-store-a-mat-object-in-android/?answer=28608#post-id-28608

but when i show the json string, that show like this:
[image]

i don't understand about that data, how can that be calculated by DescriptorMatcher.BRUTEFORCE_HAMMING ?

Comment: That data is Base64 encoded binary data. You are not supposed to understand it, its binary. If you want to retrieve the data from the database you have to first call matFromJson() from the link you posted...

Comment: @RuiMarques is this the only way to read data from Mat?

Comment: I don't understand what is your problem.

Comment: @RuiMarques  i just want to see what the result value of orb feature using extractor.compute(mat, keypoints, features);

Comment: Keypoints have coordinates. If you want to see them, draw a circle with the keypoint coordinates in your image.

Comment: @RuiMarques thanks for your help rui, and i need your help one more, this is about matching the feature, can you take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22752774/android-opencv-matching-orb-feature-from-database
thank you very much :)