# what type we can specify for surf descriptor in the mysql DB

Tags: c++, mysql, opencv

I'm using Opencv C++, for a face recognition application. For that I used SURF as descriptor and FlannMatcher for matching the points. Now I need to insert the descriptors into the database(I am using mysql DB). Can I insert descriptors into mysql DB, If yes which is the type I can use to store.

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_feature_detectors.html#keypoint , http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_descriptor_matchers.html?highlight=dmatch#DMatch , it seems like you want to store one of these. you just allocate the int & float spaces for the members.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SURF technique each of your descriptors contains 64 positions with float values. If you are using FlannMatcher probably you are using the technique Bag-of-Visual-Words, so for each image you will have 1 row and N cols filled with float values, where N is equal the number of cluster you are using.

I suggest you to create a DataBase table with 66 rows, so 1º col is for your ID the nexts N cols is for your descriptor and the last one is for your class.

You also can check that : [How to save OpenCV Keypoint features to database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21849938/how-to-save-opencv-keypoint-features-to-database)

or you can use YML files also to save your progress [files YML](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/xml_yaml_persistence.html)

Comment: Actually I want to store the SURF descriptors, as you specified earlier it has 64 position with float value. Then how can I insert this into mysql database? What should be the type I need to specify for the descriptor while inserting to the database. And how can I return it back, after returning any conversion needed or not?