# OpenCV image descriptors to JSON

Tags: java, json, opencv, mat, opencv-features2d

I want to store some image descriptors on a server so that when image matching on an android phone I can fetch the precomputed image descriptors rather then doing it on the fly. I have successfully created an application that can take an input image and output the best match but I am having some trouble with placing the image descriptor matrix into a JSON file.

Below I have placed some code that I have tried to adapt to perform the function I want but I run into an error with these lines:

```
mat.get(0, 0, data);
```

The error it gives is:

> Mat data type is not compatible: 5

The descriptor matrix is of type CV_32FC1 but it treats it as CV_8SC1. Full code is underneath, the idea is that I will pass in descriptor matrix to matToJson and then store the output on the server and then use matFromJson to retrieve the contents of the JSON file. I also cannot resolve Base64.DEFAULT as it shows an error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    public static String matToJson(Mat mat){        
    JsonObject obj = new JsonObject();

    if(mat.isContinuous()){
        int cols = mat.cols();
        int rows = mat.rows();
        int elemSize = (int) mat.elemSize();    

        byte[] data = new byte[cols * rows * elemSize];

        mat.get(0, 0, data);

        obj.addProperty("rows", mat.rows()); 
        obj.addProperty("cols", mat.cols()); 
        obj.addProperty("type", mat.type());

        // We cannot set binary data to a json object, so:
        // Encoding data byte array to Base64.
        String dataString = new String(Base64.encode(data, Base64.DEFAULT)); //Error here as well .default does not exist

        obj.addProperty("data", dataString);            

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(obj);

        return json;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Mat not continuous.");
    }
    return "{}";
}

public static Mat matFromJson(String json){
    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
    JsonObject JsonObject = parser.parse(json).getAsJsonObject();

    int rows = JsonObject.get("rows").getAsInt();
    int cols = JsonObject.get("cols").getAsInt();
    int type = JsonObject.get("type").getAsInt();

    String dataString = JsonObject.get("data").getAsString();       
    byte[] data = Base64.decode(dataString.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT); 

    Mat mat = new Mat(rows, cols, type);
    mat.put(0, 0, data);

    return mat;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution to the issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27065062/opencv-mat-object-serialization-in-java), the problem was being caused by using the incorrect data type in the array. rather than using byte it should have been float. however the solution I have linked above is much better in that it checks the data type prior to encoding the data.