# OpenCV - Java: Serializing/deserializing MatofKeypoint type descriptors found using descriptorMatcher

Tags: java, opencv, serialization, mat

I'm currently trying to serialize/deserialize descriptors found using the descriptorMatcher.compute() function. I'm using Gson's toJson and fromJason to do the serialization.

```
    MatOfKeyPoint kpFeatures = new MatOfKeyPoint();
    MatOfKeyPoint kpDescriptor = new MatOfKeyPoint();

    featureDetector.detect(sampleMat, kpFeatures);
    descriptorExtractor.compute(sampleMat, kpFeatures, kpDescriptor);

    //Serializing and deserializing the descriptors.
    //First convert the MatOfKeyPoint to an array for storage
    String serDescriptors = gson.toJson(kpDescriptor.toArray());
    MatOfKeyPoint deserDescriptors = new MatOfKeyPoint(gson.fromJson(serDescriptors, KeyPoint[].class));

    System.out.println("Original keypoint matrix: ");
    System.out.println(kpDescriptor);
    System.out.println("Deserialized keypoint matrix: ");
    System.out.println(deserDescriptors);
```

The output I get from this is:

```
Original keypoint matrix: 
Mat [ 1311*64*CV_32FC1, isCont=true, isSubmat=false, nativeObj=0xa30c010, dataAddr=0xa691660 ]
Deserialized keypoint matrix: 
Mat [ 83904*1*CV_32FC(7), isCont=true, isSubmat=false, nativeObj=0xa39b600, dataAddr=0x2b363a24d020 ]
```

My belief is that the matrix isn't getting deserialized correctly, so that running descriptorMatcher.compute() returns the following error:

> OpenCV Error: Unsupported format or combination of formats (type=53
>   ) in buildIndex_, file /local/p4clients/pkgbuild-P1uGN/workspace/src/Opencv/build/private/src/modules/flann/src/miniflann.cpp, line 315
>   Exception in thread "main" CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception: /local/p4clients/pkgbuild-P1uGN/workspace/src/Opencv/build/private/src/modules/flann/src/miniflann.cpp:315: error: (-210) type=53
>    in function buildIndex_
>   ]

I've tried the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27065062/opencv-mat-object-serialization-in-java) and [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/8873/best-way-to-store-a-mat-object-in-android/?answer=28608#post-id-28608) but haven't had much luck as the deserialized matrix always has the wrong dimensions.

How can I reconstruct a CV_32FC1 matrix from an array of keypoints?

Maybe I'm just overlooking something dumb, but any input would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use Json, it is possible to go directly to Java primitives.

#### MatOfKeyPoint to float[] or even byte[]

Using the `MatOfKeyPoint.get()` method, you can get a populated `float[]`.  Then using `ByteBuffer.putFloat()`, you can loop through all of your floats, finally getting a populated `byte[]` by using `ByteBuffer.array()`.

You also need to save some attirbutes `MatOfKeyPoint.rows()`, `MatOfKeyPoint.cols()`, and `MatOfKeyPoint.type()`.

#### float[] or byte[] to MatOfKeyPoint

To reconstitute your `MatOfKeyPoint` object, if you're coming from `byte[]`, first you make a `float[]` out of that using `ByteBuffer.wrap(blob), then run`ByteBuffer.asFloatBuffer()`.  If you're creating from`float[]`, use`FloatBuffer.get()`with a properly sized new empty`float[]` object.

Now that you have `yourFloatArray` you run `MatOfKeyPoint.create(rows, cols, type)`, those three things you had to save earlier.  Finally you run `MatOfKeyPoint.put(0, 0, yourFloatArray)`.

There is a complete Android solution, with Java code which can be found in [this StackOverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44089416/897007).  It goes farther than what your question is about, since it goes into how to store the object in a database, but the OpenCv Mat object to primitive concept is demonstrated.